# SSRS why my last row's height in last page growing?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a trouble with my SSRS page.
I added 1 tablix.
Why my last row on the last page expanded?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Some times it is due to the width of the report/tablix body, if you have space  on with reduce it.
2. check tablix page break

[image]